# How to create sub directory(folder) in google drive using Google drive api v3 & php?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a folder called summary in root directory of my Google Drive account. I want would like to do is create a sub folder under summary called January so I have something like this.

> Root
>   -> Summary
>   ---> January

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Add **parents** parameter in **Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile** object.

```
$folderId = 'drive folder(summary) id';  
$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
        'name' => 'january',
        'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
        'parents' => array($folderId) //to create sub dir. under summary folder
));
$file = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata, array('fields' => 'id'));
```

Comment: $fileMetadata should be $folderInfo.
Still doesn't work for me, but thanks.
Google is start to piss me off!